# why email uses different protocols?

Tags: email, networking, tcp, smtp, pop3

Why can not we send an email using HTTP protocols? An email contains text, so why cant it be send using HTTP?. I searched in every where. But can not understand those documents.So please help me to understand this

Comment: SMTP is 15 years older than HTTP, so it was there first.

Comment: OSI has no relevance to this question, nor to anything else in the last twenty years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The protocols to transfer mails  (SMTP, POP, IMAP) are all built on top of TCP and HTTP it built on top of TCP too. At least SMTP and POP are older protocols than HTTP.

Of course you could in theory built some mail transfer protocol on top of HTTP. But this effectively means to rebuilt the functionality we already have on top of TCP so that it now is built on top of HTTP which is on top of TCP again. So this is mostly another layer of complexity without actually gaining a lot.

But I'm pretty sure that they were already several attempts to built SOAP, REST,... API's which care about mail transport. But probably none of this showed to be significantly better than the old protocols we already have, which means that we don't switch the existing infrastructure we have to a new protocol in the foreseeable future. It's not that the existing protocols are that good but to take the effort to replace all of this a new protocol must be significantly better.